# TensorFlow; Error in attempting to print out the loss value of CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to modify the MNIST_deep.py, provided by Tensorflow.org, to display the loss value. Below is a fragment of the code:

```
print ("\n***** Training a prediction model... *****\n")
print ("Model: Convolutional Neural Network, Activation: ReLU + Softmax\n")

for i in range(20000):
    batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y, keep_prob: 0.5})
    [_, Avg_Cost] = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict = {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})

    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={x: batch_x, y_: batch_y, keep_prob: 1.0})

        if (Debugged == True):
            print("Step = %05d, Training accuracy = %.2f" % (i, train_accuracy), "Average Cost = ", Avg_Cost)

        else:
            print("Step = %05d, Training accuracy = %.2f" % (i, train_accuracy))
```

The problem is this line:

```
[_, Avg_Cost] = sess.run([train_step, cross_entropy], feed_dict = {x: batch_x, y: batch_y})
```

It keeps telling me that the shape [-1, 10] has negative dimensions. I'm fairly new to TensorFlow, I cannot figure out where the problem is. Could you help me track the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your code is that you don't pass a value for `keep_prob` in your call to `sess.run`. It is passed on the line just above. Unless it is redundant on that line, you would need it on the following line as well.

If that does not solve your problem, please post or link a full version of the code to reproduce this.